# validation of data in a registration form

Tags: php

i am doing a program to validate a data i.e checking whether the entered username is present in the database or not.But i am finding that the code is not entering the first if condition i.e.`if ($result->num_rows > 0) {`

```
<?php  
include('custdb.php');
session_start();
$f=0;
//$user=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username']);
//$pass=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);
//$fetch=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM `info` WHERE username='".$uname."' and password='".$pass."'");
//$_SESSION['info_username']=$user;
//header("Location:custprofile.php");
echo $uname=$_POST['username'];
 echo "<br>";
 echo $pass=$_POST['password'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `info` WHERE `email`=".$uname;
 $result = $conn->query($sql);
 echo"done";
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        if($uname==$row["email"])
        {
            $f=1;
        }
        else
        {
            $f=0;
        }


    //echo '<h4 align="left"><a href="update.php?id='.$pro_id.'&qty='.$qty.'">Update Quantity</a> </h4>';   
}
if($f==1)
{
   header("Location:custprofile.php"); 
}
else
{
    header("Location:custindex.php"); 
}
}
else {
     echo "0 results";
}

?>
```

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure that you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: you are getting username in $_POST and matching `email`

Comment: They are using the email address for the username @Vicky, or seem to be.

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? You're making an assumption the query is working.
Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with your sql query. The quotes around $uname are missing.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `info` WHERE `email`='".$uname."';";
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: OK, my bad. The quotes around $uname are missing. I asked the OP to "try" because I don't know if it'll work, since I don't know if $_POST['username'] retrieves anything :)

Comment: What @JayBlanchard refers (or at least what I think about) is that you should have to edit your answer, instead to put it in a comment to allows people that arrives here to see clearly what the solution to the problem is.

Comment: Thank you Error404, it's quite difficult to be a beginner in the SO jungle ^^

Comment: @D14n4 You are welcome :) It is a bit difficult at the beginning but there is always time to learn :)